# ESP-WROOM-32: Invalid head of packet (0x46)

Tags: esp8266, esp32

I'm trying to flash a program to ESP-WROOM-32. When I run `make flash`, I get the following error. I tried this with 3 different ESP-32s and I get the same error. Also, when I try `make erase_flash` I get the same error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Toolchain path: /home/me/esp/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc
Toolchain version: esp-2020r3-49-gd5524c1
Compiler version: 8.4.0
Python requirements from /opt/esp8266-rtos-sdk/requirements.txt are satisfied.
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
App "test" version: 85cf410
Flashing binaries to serial port /dev/ttyUSB0 (app at offset 0x10000)...
esptool.py v2.4.0
Connecting.....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: **:**:**:**:**:**
Uploading stub...
Running stub...

A fatal error occurred: Invalid head of packet (0x46)
make: *** [/opt/esp8266-rtos-sdk/components/esptool_py/Makefile.projbuild:76: flash] Error 2
```

Baud rate: 115200 (tried higher ones in serial flasher config, same issue)

EDIT: I tried flashing a program from examples using Arduino IDE and it worked fine. So, it just seems to fail when using the ESP-IDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by me using the old RTOS SDK, which I used with ESP-01, with ESP-32. It seems that the project structure and build tools have changed quite a bit now. I used the [ESP-IDF](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf) to build and flash the program and now it's working.

Comment: kovac - Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to effectively mark the topic as solved, please consider "[áccepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)" your choice of the best answer i.e. click the "tick mark" next to an answer to make it green - either [your answer](/help/self-answer) (which can be áccepted after 2023-05-30 @ 08.52 UTC i.e. 48 hrs after the question was asked) or another answer, if one is written (which can be accepted any time). That shows you don't need more help & future readers can quickly see the confirmed solution. Thanks.